# VuetifyJS, router-link not showing up as a cursor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

```
<router-link to="/" tag="span" style="{ cursor: pointer; }">Name</router-link>
```

But style is not applied and cursor remains text cursor when the mouse is over this element.

Full code:

```
<v-toolbar-title class="white--text">
  <router-link to="/" tag="span" exact style="{ cursor: pointer; }">Name</router-link>
</v-toolbar-title>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this version. Bind the `style` tag.

```
<router-link to="/" tag="span" exact :style="{ cursor: 'pointer'}">Name</router-link>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GvReNV?editors=1010).